# "For input in answer" QUIZ Actionscript

Tags: for-loop, actionscript, multidimensional-array, actionscript-2

The questions are random but they show what I need.
As you can see for answer[0], I had to specify three possible answers. I want to be able to state that the answer's correct if "bill" is written anywhere in their answer.
But this won't work

```
for (var i = 0; i < answer[index].length; i++)
{
    for (answer[index][i] in answer_input.text.toLowerCase())
    {
        correct = true;

    }


answer = new Array();
answer[0] =  ["your name is bill","bill's your name","your name's bill"]
answer[1] = ["john", "sean", "greg"]
question = new Array();
question[0] = "whats my name?"
question[1] = "whats not my name?"
index = 0;

onEnterFrame = function ()
{
    question_txt.text = question[index];
};

enter1.onRelease = function()
{
    question_txt.text = question[index];
    var correct = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < answer[index].length; i++)
    {
        if (answer[index][i] == answer_input.text.toLowerCase())
        {
            correct = true;

        }
    }

    if (correct)
    {
        index++;
        answer_input.text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        answer_input.text = "Incorrect";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to check if "bill" is written anywhere in the answer why not use

```
answer_input.text.toLowerCase().indexOf( "bill", 0 )
```

If "bill" is in there the function will return the index where it occurred in the answer. If it's not there, -1 will be returned.